# Setting a timeout to pdo_mssql in zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-db

I have one or 2 queries that take ~ 10 minutes to execute.

How do I manipulate the $db object to include timeouts?

```
$_SESSION['params'] = array(
 'host'           => '127.0.0.1',
 'username'       => 'sa',
 'password'       => 'password',
 'dbname'         => 'schema',
 'driver_options'        => $options
);
$db = createConnection($_SESSION['params']);

function createConnection( $params){
    return Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_MSsql', $params);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the `PDO_MSSQL` adapter, but according to the documentation, you can use the `driver_options` parameter to add specific options to the adapter. See the example #7 in http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting.parameters

If there is a `PDO_MSSQL` parameter to set the timeout, you should be able to set it there.

**EDIT:**

There seems to be a `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT` attribute. According to the PHP documentation:

> `PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT`: Specifies the timeout duration in seconds. Not all drivers support this option, and it's meaning may differ from driver to driver. For example, sqlite will wait for up to this time value before giving up on obtaining an writable lock, but other drivers may interpret this as a connect or a read timeout interval. Requires int.

**EDIT2:**

There seems to be a custom attribute for the `pdo_mssql` driver. According to [this blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2010/08/04/microsoft-drivers-for-php-for-sql-server-2-0-released.aspx):

> Developers can set the query timeout using the PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT per connection and per statement, and exploit it to provide a better user experience in their applications.

Hope that helps,

Comment: PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT doesnt seem to affect the pdo_mssql driver

Comment: @Alex: I've re-edited my answer, there seems to be a PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_QUERY_TIMEOUT attribute. Didn't test it though, I hope it's useful for you.